# SublimePicker: background color has changed with new Android SDK

Tags: android

I use this excellent library: https://github.com/vikramkakkar/SublimePicker/

I've upgraded to Android SDK 27.1.0 and now the background color of the Sublime picker has a grey color instead white...

This is my original style:

```
<style name="DateTimePickerDefault" parent="SublimePickerStyleLight">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_accent_3</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/theme_primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/icon_theme_primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/icon_theme_primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#727272</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/theme_primary</item>
    </style>
```

Have you got some ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I use the reflexion process to set background color correctly to the main view.

```
public class ExtendSublimePicker extends SublimePicker {

    private int mBackgroundColor = Color.WHITE; // By default

    public ExtendSublimePicker(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExtendSublimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        refreshBackgroundColor();
    }

    public ExtendSublimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        refreshBackgroundColor();
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ExtendSublimePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        refreshBackgroundColor();
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackgroundColor(@ColorInt int color) {
        mBackgroundColor = color;
        refreshBackgroundColor();
    }

    private void refreshBackgroundColor() {
        Field field = getField(getClass(), "llMainContentHolder");
        if (field != null) {
            try {
                View view = (View) field.get(this);
                view.setBackgroundColor(mBackgroundColor);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }

    private static Field getField(Class<?> cls, String fieldName) {
        for (Class<?> c = cls; c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
            try {
                final Field field = c.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return field;
            } catch (final NoSuchFieldException e) {
                // Try parent
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Cannot access field " + cls.getName() + "." + fieldName, e);
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Cannot find field " + cls.getName() + "." + fieldName);
    }
}
```